# Calling a function without parameters

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-5

I found the following through trial and error. Mainly error. 
So it's Stoopid Question Time™...

Why does Javascript *not* kick up an error when calling a function with no parameters? Why would you want that?

```
something // call the function but forgot about the parameters

function something()
{
  // some code here
  alert("Working on it!");
}
```

Comment: The statement `something` by itself is pretty much the same thing as the statement `7` by itself. It doesn't do anything, but it's not an error.

Answer (score 4):

Because functions are first-class members in Javascript - they can be referenced like any expression. For example, maybe you wanted to store it in another variable:

```js
function foo() { console.log('foo'); }

const anotherReferenceToFoo = foo;
anotherReferenceToFoo();
```

Or maybe you wanted to *pass* the function itself, without calling it, such as to `addEventListener`:

```js
function foo() { console.log('foo'); }
button.addEventListener('click', foo);
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Or to `setTimeout`:

```js
function foo() { console.log('foo'); }
setTimeout(foo, 1000);
```

Referencing a function name without calling it is a very useful technique. Without it, many things would be impossible.

If you have *just the line* `something`, with nothing else on it, this is not an error for the same reason that an unused expression is not an error:

```js
'5';

true;

() => 'foo';

console.log('syntax is fine');
```

If you want to make sure you don't make these sorts of mistakes, consider installing ESLint and enforce the [no-unused-expressions](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions) rule.